# Vue and TS ignore shims files

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm working on a project that is based on VUE and TS, and it seems like the shims files dont work. The project is swarmed by infinite errors like

```html
Property '$store' does not exist on type 'Dashboard'.
Property "$router" does not exist on type 'Dashboard'.
```

My store and my router work well, but the compiler doesn't agree with that, that's why I decided to adapt for TS and add some shims.d.ts files.

The shims file looks like that

```js
import { VueRouter } from "vue-router/types/router";
import { Route } from "vue-router";

declare module "vue/types/vue" {
  interface Vue {
    $router: VueRouter;
    $route: Route;
  }
}
```

And it doesn't work! Property "$router" does not exist on type 'Dashboard'.

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitThis": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "typeRoots": [
        "./node_modules/@types",
      "./src/@types/",
    ],
    "types": [
      "webpack-env"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

The shims files are located in project_name/src/@types/ folder.

Comment: Where is the shims file located? Did you try restarting the IDE to ensure the file is indexed? (That's sometimes needed in VS Code)

Comment: updated the question. ide reset didnt help